# linkedin objective-c library scope email address

Tags: objective-c, linkedin-api

I am trying to update the Linkedin Objective-c library
https://github.com/synedra/LinkedIn-OAuth-Sample-Client

to allow for the retrieval of email address.

How can I do that?

I tried changing

```
OARequestParameter *nameParam = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"scope"
                                                                   value:@"r_fullprofile r_contactinfo r_emailaddress"];
NSArray *params = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nameParam, nil];
[request setParameters:params];
OARequestParameter * scopeParameter=[OARequestParameter requestParameter:@"scope" value:@"r_fullprofile r_contactinfo r_emailaddress"];

[request setParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:scopeParameter]];
```

but that is not working

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do all this stuff, just select your required scope in your app settings whatever you want. Keep the code as simple as below. Linked in login view will automatically display you all your selected scope.

```
- (void)requestTokenFromProvider
    {

         OAMutableURLRequest *request = 
                [[[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:requestTokenURL
                                                 consumer:self.consumer
                                                    token:nil   
                                                 callback:linkedInCallbackURL
                                        signatureProvider:nil] autorelease];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];  

        OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[[OADataFetcher alloc] init] autorelease];
        [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                             delegate:self
                    didFinishSelector:@selector(requestTokenResult:didFinish:)
                      didFailSelector:@selector(requestTokenResult:didFail:)];

    }
```